# Get form values into an array in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to get form field values into an array? Example:

```php
<?php
     array('one', 'two', 'three');
?>
```

```html
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="test1" value="one" />
    <input type="hidden" name="test2" value="two" />
    <input type="hidden" name="test3" value="three" />
    <input type="submit" value="Test Me" />
</form>
```

Is it possible to pass all form values no matter the number of them to the array in PHP?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It already is done.

Look at the `$_POST` array.

If you do a `print_r($_POST);` you should see that it is an array.

If you just need the values and not the key, use

```
$values = array_values($_POST);
```

Reference: *[$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)*

Comment: Great, how could I get rid of the submit button from the array being posted? And how could I add some elements to the array?

Comment: I wouldn't add anything to that array. As for buttons, just leave the name field off.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, just name the inputs the same thing and place brackets after each one:

```html
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="test[]" value="one" />
    <input type="hidden" name="test[]" value="two" />
    <input type="hidden" name="test[]" value="three" />
    <input type="submit" value="Test Me" />
</form>
```

Then you can test with:

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST['test']);
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is actually the way that PHP was designed to work, and one of the reasons it achieved a large market penetration early on with web programming.

When you submit a form to a PHP script, all the form data is put into superglobal arrays that are accessible at any time.  So for instance, submitting the form you put in your question:

```html
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="test1" value="one" />
    <input type="hidden" name="test2" value="two" />
    <input type="hidden" name="test3" value="three" />
    <input type="submit" value="Test Me" />
</form>
```

would mean that inside `test.php`, you would have a superglobal named [`$_POST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) that would be prefilled as if you had created it with the form data, essentially as follows:

```
$_POST = array('test1'=>'one', 'test2'=>'two', 'test3'=>'three');
```

There are superglobals for both POST and GET requests, i.e., `$_POST`, [`$_GET`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).  There is one for cookie data, [`$_COOKIE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php).  There is also [`$_REQUEST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php), which contains a combination of all three.

See the [documentation page on superglobals](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) for more information.